# counting-steps Euclidean algorithm program in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I need a program to count the number of steps required by Euclid’s algorithm to find gcd(a, b) in Python. The program may based on Lam´e’s theorem. 
I just got the simple Euclidean algorithm program so far which is:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a
```

I have no idea how to write the program I need.

Comment: Couldn't you just run the algorithm and, well, count it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize a counter integer object, `count` to zero and increment it each time round the loop:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    count = 0
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
        count += 1
    print(count)
    return a
```

Lamé's theorem says that the number of steps, `count` will never exceed 5 times the number of digits in `b` (the smaller number). To verify this:

```
import math
def gcd(a, b):
    ndigits = int(math.log10(b)) + 1
    count = 0
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
        count += 1
    print(count)
    print("Lame's theorem holds?", count <= 5*ndigits)
    return a
```